# Display the second line of a string in java

Tags: java, string, printing, line

Given a String like :

```
String str= "line1
line2
line3
line4";
```

How to display one specific line? For example the third one, like

```
System.out.println([...]str[...]);
```

which in terminal will display:

```
line3
```

Comment: You can't have a String like the one in your example because Java won't let you split strings over multiple lines without concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the split statement. It separates strings by a given regex. In this case the regex would be \n:

```
String[] lines;

  String regex= "\\n";
  lines = str.split(regex);
```

you can then acces line 3 by using:

```
String line3 = lines[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your input string depending on its formatting..

```
System.out.println(str.split('\\n')[2]);
```

See documentation for `split()` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] strings = str.split('\\n');
if (strings.length > 1){
  return strings[1];
}
```

Comment: split() function returns String[]. This code will not compile.

Comment: What if it's is a BufferedReader ? Is that the same procedure?

Comment: @mastermind - No. That changes things because BufferedReader has a readLine() method that'll do the splitting on [\r]\n for you.